# How can I improve the quality of a voronoi style mesh

Tags: modifiers, workflow

I have been trying a few method to try to create a voronoi style organic type mesh.

My current method is as follows

1. Create a shape

[image: Shape]

2. Cell fracture (using a partial system for good distribution)

[image: Cell fracture]

3. Merge by distance (using the slider to remove verts which are too close)

[image: Merge by distance applied]

4. Delete any edges which would cause too many elements

[image: Deleted excess edges]

5. Apply modifier - Skin

[image: Skin]

6. Apply modifier - Subdivide

[image: subdivide]

7. Apply modifier - Remesh

[image: Remesh]

8. Apply modifier - subdivide

[image: subdivided - second time]

The result is sort of what I'm looking for, but I was hoping it would be smoother.

I have been trying to get working on this with sverchok (using the scipy module to use 3D voronoi, but I cant seem to get pip working to install it - I have another thread open about that as well). So currently this is my method.

Does anyone know of any other method for achieving similar result which are smoother final surface texture or product something similar with less steps in the workflow.

Having to go through a delete excess edges manually is not ideal.

Any suggesting would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, how about taking the first step, but making the shape smoother and then doing the other steps?

Comment: Triangulating the remesh modifier after applying it could help

Comment: Hi Aster17, thanks for the comment, but I was refering to the surface texture rather than the low poly style of the initial model. Sorry for not being clear about that, ill edit my question.

Comment: Scratch what I said earlier, Just use a second round of subdivision.

Comment: You need to either lower the remesh cell size to increase the detail density, or lower it so there the surface is smoother

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of mesh voronoi, but we can handle surface and solid shape voronoi also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have seen that sverchok is a great way to do 3D Voronoi but I just can’t seem to be able to get pip to allow me to install the dependency for 3D voronoi.

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751469/blender-trying-to-install-sverchok-addon-scipy-package-but-pip-is-out-of-date

Comment: I have now been able to get scipy working by downloading it through python system rather than in blender and then renaming the blender python folder so blender now uses my systems python and it's all good I can now get the 3D voronoi node and I am in the early stages of learning how to use it. Thanks!